# Why is an existing field that has not changed be suddenly considered to have an invalid data type?

Tags: reporting-services, types, sqldatatypes, rdl

I am modifying a legacy SSRS report (rdl file); I've added four columns to it, and am supplying those values by means of a new data source (Stored Procedure).

However, now when I try to run the report via the "Preview" tab, I get:

*An error occured during local report processing.
The Group expression used in grouping 'table1_Group1' returned a data type that is not valid.
" [ a second err msg identical to the one above ] "*

There is indeed a Row Group named "table1_Group1", and its properties look like this:

[image]

I don't know why NewBiz is suddenly a problem; nothing has changed about it, and there was no complaint concerning it previously.

"NewBiz" does (still) appear in the filed list in the "Dataset Properties" pane (both Field Name and Field Source are "NewBiz"); the data source (stored proc) does return it. So...?!?

NOTE: The "table1_Details_Group" beneath "table1_Group1" has no Group Expression, and thus seems to have no raison d'etre; unless I'm misunderstanding something about its role/purpose.

### UPDATE

Alan Schofield raised the question over whether the dataset fields "are in the order expected."

So I examined that under a fine-toothed microscope. This is the last part of the data source/stored procedure, which returns the values:

```
select CY.CSDirector, CY.Category, CY.Segment, CY._Unit, 
       CU.New, CU.Assumed, CU.Existing, CU.Organic, 
       CY.NumUnits, CY.NumUnitsLast, CY.MonthSales, CY.MonthSalesLast, 
       CY.MonthPerc, CY.YTDSales, CY.YTDSalesLast, CY.YTDPerc,
       CY.ProjSales, CY.YTDProjSales, CY.YTDBudgetPerc, CY.NewBiz 
from #CombinedYears CY
left join #CategorizedUnits CU on CU.Unit = CY._Unit
```

And this is what I see in the Report Data pane for the data surce:

[image]

So the first possible discrepency is in that "_Unit" is seen as "ID_Unit" for some reason in the Dataset. Why would that be? Does SSRS automatically convert "*" to "ID*"? If this is a known gotcha, it is as yet unkown to me.

After that all Dallas breaks loose, as the order of fields diverge radically. Why? Shouldn't the Refresh have ordered them alike? How can I get them to straighten up and fly right, or manually change the order so that they match?

NOTE: I'm not sure if this should even matter - should it? Are the field values populated based on position rather than by field name? IOW, must they match up, positionally?

### UPDATE 2

[This](https://simplesqlserver.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/ssrs-dataset-move-up-and-down-2/) woke me up to the fact that there are up/down arrows; I'll try that...

### UPDATE 3

I changed the order of the fields in the list to match those returned from the stored procedure, but it made no difference - I still get the same err msg when I try to generate the report.

### UPDATE 4

In the rdl file the group expression that is supposedly problematic is this:

```
  <TablixRowHierarchy>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember>
          <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
          <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember>
          <Group Name="table1_Group1">
            <GroupExpressions>
              <GroupExpression>=Fields!NewBiz.Value</GroupExpression>
            </GroupExpressions>
          </Group>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="table1_Details_Group">
                <DataElementName>Detail</DataElementName>
              </Group>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
              <DataElementName>Detail_Collection</DataElementName>
              <DataElementOutput>Output</DataElementOutput>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepWithGroup>Before</KeepWithGroup>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember>
          <KeepWithGroup>Before</KeepWithGroup>
          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        </TablixMember>
      </TablixMembers>
    </TablixRowHierarchy>
```

...to be more specific, this:

```
  <Group Name="table1_Group1">
    <GroupExpressions>
      <GroupExpression>=Fields!NewBiz.Value</GroupExpression>
    </GroupExpressions>
  </Group>
```

Why would that be a problem? NewBiz is a value contained in the result set, and it has two values by which it could be grouped (-1, signifying "New", and 0, signifying "Existing").

So why the err msg?

That field itself is represented in the rdl file like so:

```
<Field Name="NewBiz">
  <DataField>NewBiz</DataField>
  <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

### UPDATE 5

And now it's working, with now change to the code...this happens too often with this old technology, and I don't know whether to be more relieved or irritated when something that doesn't work all of a sudden starts working WITH NO CODE CHANGES. Why!?? Arghhhh!!! Gleeeep!!! (that last was a happy sound, more-or-less equating to the polar opposite of argh).

Comment: If you execute the dataset query from within the report designer, does [NewBiz] look to contain sensible values? And, have you refreshed the dataset fields to make sure they are in the order expected.

Comment: By "within the report designer" do you mean separate from the "Preview" tab? If so, I don't know how i would go about attempting that...

Comment: The query that I can run from LINQPad, that is as much as possible just like the SP, does return valid values for "NewBIz" - they are all either -1 or 0.

Comment: Yes, I did refresh the fields - that's how I got the new four fields to appear and be available.

Comment: Alan, please see the Update.

Comment: This is from memory, I'm away from my desk now. If you right-click the dataset name in the designer as per your image) click Query and (you may have to switch to "Edit As text") then you  can hit the execute button and see the exact output that your report iS trying to render.

Comment: Sounds like stale meta-data and/or Visual Studio has cached some report data.

Comment: @AlanSchofield: That worked just fine; the data looks good - it all makes sense and seems to be in the right place (the values match the columns). Vals for the new columns are there, where they should be, so I don't know what the underlying problem really is...

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest other than some pragmatic process of elimination. Could you copy the RDL, strip out anything not directly related to the tablix with the issue. Then output the content of your current dataset directly into a new database table. Next, edit the new RDL to point directly to that new table rather than using the original query. See where you get with that. If there is still a problem you will at least have an rdl and some data you could post for others to test with.

Comment: Please see Update 5 - it's working now, although no changes were made.

Comment: Are there any filters on the group?

Comment: @Snowlockk: I don't know, but it's working now, and that is legacy code that shouldn't change, so as long as it's working, that's all I care about.

Comment: Scary thing is you don't know if the problem will resurface if it suddenly disappear. Did you test with the same data all the time? could be a data centric problem.

Comment: Yeah, the same data that failed before now works; and other data works, too, so it was obviously a conspiracy on the part of some foreign agent to make me waste time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had a chart being fed by a 3-column query, one of which was an aggregate (ID Code, Sum(Count), and Day - in that order). What I did to fix it was to put the field I was grouping by earlier in my query (i.e. Day, ID Code, and Sum(Count)), that seemed to do the trick. It seems kind of stupid... but there it is.